# I get Unexpected value. Eror When ı tried to get data from an api

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my data fetch function.
Here ı fetch to get data from url.

```
Future<Pokedex> gonderiGetir() async {
  String url =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"; //Url adresimiz
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url),);
  var response_body = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Pokedex.fromJson(response_body);
  } 
  else {
    throw Exception("Baglanamadık ${response.statusCode}");
  }
}
```

This is my model for use it.
I created this class automatically from this website. https://app.quicktype.io/
I tried to print the data using debugprint more than once in the code I created, but I could not succeed.
I cannot access the data in a way that I cannot understand. I need your help on this issue, if you don't help, I can't solve the problem because I'm new to mobile application development and I'm trying to develop an application using API for the first time.

```
    import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Pokedex pokedexFromJson(String str) => Pokedex.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String pokedexToJson(Pokedex data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

    class Pokedex {
      Pokedex({
        required this.pokemon,
      });
    
      List<Pokemon> pokemon;
    
      factory Pokedex.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pokedex(
            pokemon: json["pokemon"] == null
                ? []
                : List<Pokemon>.from(
                    json["pokemon"].map((x) => Pokemon.fromJson(x))),
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "pokemon": pokemon == []
                ? null
                : List<dynamic>.from(pokemon.map((x) => x.toJson())),
          };
    }
    
    class Pokemon {
      Pokemon({
        required this.id,
        required this.num,
        required this.name,
        required this.img,
        required this.type,
        required this.height,
        required this.weight,
        required this.candy,
        required this.candyCount,
        required this.egg,
        required this.spawnChance,
        required this.avgSpawns,
        required this.spawnTime,
        required this.multipliers,
        required this.weaknesses,
        required this.nextEvolution,
        required this.prevEvolution,
      });
    
      int id;
      String num;
      String name;
      String img;
      List<String> type;
      String height;
      String weight;
      String candy;
      int candyCount;
      String egg;
      double spawnChance;
      double avgSpawns;
      String spawnTime;
      List<double> multipliers;
      List<String> weaknesses;
      List<Evolution> nextEvolution;
      List<Evolution> prevEvolution;
    
      factory Pokemon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pokemon(
            id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
            num: json["num"] == null ? null : json["num"],
            name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
            img: json["img"] == null ? null : json["img"],
            type: json["type"] == null
                ? []
                : List<String>.from(json["type"].map((x) => x)),
            height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
            weight: json["weight"] == null ? null : json["weight"],
            candy: json["candy"] == null ? null : json["candy"],
            candyCount: json["candy_count"] == null ? null : json["candy_count"],
            egg: json["egg"] == null ? null : json["egg"],
            spawnChance: json["spawn_chance"] == null
                ? null
                : json["spawn_chance"].toDouble(),
            avgSpawns:
                json["avg_spawns"] == null ? null : json["avg_spawns"].toDouble(),
            spawnTime: json["spawn_time"] == null ? null : json["spawn_time"],
            multipliers: json["multipliers"] == null
                ? []
                : List<double>.from(json["multipliers"].map((x) => x.toDouble())),
            weaknesses: json["weaknesses"] == null
                ? []
                : List<String>.from(json["weaknesses"].map((x) => x)),
            nextEvolution: json["next_evolution"] == null
                ? []
                : List<Evolution>.from(
                    json["next_evolution"].map((x) => Evolution.fromJson(x))),
            prevEvolution: json["prev_evolution"] == null
                ? []
                : List<Evolution>.from(
                    json["prev_evolution"].map((x) => Evolution.fromJson(x))),
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id == null ? null : id,
            "num": num == null ? null : num,
            "name": name == null ? null : name,
            "img": img == null ? null : img,
            "type": type == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(type.map((x) => x)),
            "height": height == null ? null : height,
            "weight": weight == null ? null : weight,
            "candy": candy == null ? null : candy,
            "candy_count": candyCount == null ? null : candyCount,
            "egg": egg == null ? null : egg,
            "spawn_chance": spawnChance == null ? null : spawnChance,
            "avg_spawns": avgSpawns == null ? null : avgSpawns,
            "spawn_time": spawnTime == null ? null : spawnTime,
            "multipliers": multipliers == null
                ? null
                : List<dynamic>.from(multipliers.map((x) => x)),
            "weaknesses": weaknesses == null
                ? null
                : List<dynamic>.from(weaknesses.map((x) => x)),
            "next_evolution": nextEvolution == null
                ? null
                : List<dynamic>.from(nextEvolution.map((x) => x.toJson())),
            "prev_evolution": prevEvolution == null
                ? null
                : List<dynamic>.from(prevEvolution.map((x) => x.toJson())),
          };
    }
    
    class Evolution {
      Evolution({
        required this.num,
        required this.name,
      });
    
      String num;
      String name;
    
      factory Evolution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Evolution(
            num: json["num"] == null ? null : json["num"],
            name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
          );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "num": num == null ? null : num,
            "name": name == null ? null : name,
          };
    }
```

This is my result body :

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: gonderiGetir(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Pokedex> gelenPokedex) {
              if (gelenPokedex.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (gelenPokedex.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.done) {
                return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      debugPrint("gelen değer :" +
                          gelenPokedex.data!.pokemon[index].name
                              .toString());
                      return Text(gelenPokedex.data!.pokemon[index].name);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Hata"),
                );
              }
            })



    import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Pokedex pokedexFromJson(String str) => Pokedex.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String pokedexToJson(Pokedex data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Pokedex {
  Pokedex({
    required this.pokemon,
  });

  List<Pokemon> pokemon;

  factory Pokedex.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pokedex(
        pokemon: json["pokemon"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Pokemon>.from(
                json["pokemon"].map((x) => Pokemon.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pokemon": pokemon == []
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(pokemon.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Pokemon {
  Pokemon({
    required this.id,
    required this.num,
    required this.name,
    required this.img,
    required this.type,
    required this.height,
    required this.weight,
    required this.candy,
    required this.candyCount,
    required this.egg,
    required this.spawnChance,
    required this.avgSpawns,
    required this.spawnTime,
    required this.multipliers,
    required this.weaknesses,
    required this.nextEvolution,
    required this.prevEvolution,
  });

  int id;
  String num;
  String name;
  String img;
  List<String> type;
  String height;
  String weight;
  String candy;
  int candyCount;
  String egg;
  double spawnChance;
  double avgSpawns;
  String spawnTime;
  List<double> multipliers;
  List<String> weaknesses;
  List<Evolution> nextEvolution;
  List<Evolution> prevEvolution;

  factory Pokemon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pokemon(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        num: json["num"] == null ? null : json["num"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        img: json["img"] == null ? null : json["img"],
        type: json["type"] == null
            ? []
            : List<String>.from(json["type"].map((x) => x)),
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
        weight: json["weight"] == null ? null : json["weight"],
        candy: json["candy"] == null ? null : json["candy"],
        candyCount: json["candy_count"] == null ? null : json["candy_count"],
        egg: json["egg"] == null ? null : json["egg"],
        spawnChance: json["spawn_chance"] == null
            ? null
            : json["spawn_chance"].toDouble(),
        avgSpawns:
            json["avg_spawns"] == null ? null : json["avg_spawns"].toDouble(),
        spawnTime: json["spawn_time"] == null ? null : json["spawn_time"],
        multipliers: json["multipliers"] == null
            ? []
            : List<double>.from(json["multipliers"].map((x) => x.toDouble())),
        weaknesses: json["weaknesses"] == null
            ? []
            : List<String>.from(json["weaknesses"].map((x) => x)),
        nextEvolution: json["next_evolution"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Evolution>.from(
                json["next_evolution"].map((x) => Evolution.fromJson(x))),
        prevEvolution: json["prev_evolution"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Evolution>.from(
                json["prev_evolution"].map((x) => Evolution.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "num": num == null ? null : num,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "img": img == null ? null : img,
        "type": type == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(type.map((x) => x)),
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
        "weight": weight == null ? null : weight,
        "candy": candy == null ? null : candy,
        "candy_count": candyCount == null ? null : candyCount,
        "egg": egg == null ? null : egg,
        "spawn_chance": spawnChance == null ? null : spawnChance,
        "avg_spawns": avgSpawns == null ? null : avgSpawns,
        "spawn_time": spawnTime == null ? null : spawnTime,
        "multipliers": multipliers == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(multipliers.map((x) => x)),
        "weaknesses": weaknesses == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(weaknesses.map((x) => x)),
        "next_evolution": nextEvolution == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(nextEvolution.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "prev_evolution": prevEvolution == null
            ? null
            : List<dynamic>.from(prevEvolution.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Evolution {
  Evolution({
    required this.num,
    required this.name,
  });

  String num;
  String name;

  factory Evolution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Evolution(
        num: json["num"] == null ? null : json["num"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "num": num == null ? null : num,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
      };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to with your future return value since you are decoding already and then putting it in a decode function you won't get value.
Change your function to something like this.

```
Future<PokeDex> gonderiGetir() async {
  String url =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"; //Url adresimiz
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  var response_body = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return pokedexFromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Baglanamadık ${response.statusCode}");
  }
}
```

Full functional code sample code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mysample/pokeDex.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
Future<PokeDex> gonderiGetir() async {
  String url =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"; //Url adresimiz
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  var response_body = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return pokeDexFromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Baglanamadık ${response.statusCode}");
  }
}

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('The MaterialBanner is below'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: gonderiGetir(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<PokeDex> gelenPokedex) {
              if (gelenPokedex.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (gelenPokedex.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      debugPrint("gelen değer :" +
                          gelenPokedex.data!.pokemon![index].name.toString());
                      return Text(gelenPokedex.data!.pokemon![index].name!);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Hata"),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I used your sample code but the problem is not solved.
Then I thought it was a problem with the data and I used the attached code I still get the same problem.


child: Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                future: gonderiGetir(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Pokedex> gelenPokedex) {
                  return Text(gelenPokedex.data!.pokemon[0].name);
                },
              ))

Comment: @Kubilay I have verified and checked the sample code given at the last. It gives me the list of all the pokemon in gridview easily. Just try starting a new project and paste this sample code there and import http package and it will work.

Comment: @Kubilay and ofc add that model file as well.

Comment: I did it but not worked. Now ı share my model file.